# how can I send hyperlinks in GCM ?when I paste a link its turn into text

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-cloud-messaging

```
private void sendMessage() {
    final String message = this.inputMessage.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    String endPoint = EndPoints.CHAT_ROOM_MESSAGE.replace("_ID_", chatRoomId);

    this.inputMessage.setText("");

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            endPoint, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                // check for error
                if (obj.getBoolean("error") == false) {
                    JSONObject commentObj = obj.getJSONObject("message");

                    String commentId = commentObj.getString("message_id");
                    String commentText = commentObj.getString("message");
                    String createdAt = commentObj.getString("created_at");

                    JSONObject userObj = obj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String userId = userObj.getString("user_id");
                    String userName = userObj.getString("name");
                    User user = new User(userId, userName, null);

                    Message message = new Message();
                    message.setId(commentId);
                    message.setMessage(commentText);
                    message.setCreatedAt(createdAt);
                    message.setUser(user);

                    messageArrayList.add(message);

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (mAdapter.getItemCount() > 1) {
                        // scrolling to bottom of the recycler view
                        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            inputMessage.setText(message);
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id", MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser().getId());
            params.put("message", message);

            Log.e(TAG, "Params: " + params.toString());

            return params;
        };
    };


    // disabling retry policy so that it won't make
    // multiple http calls
    int socketTimeout = 0;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    strReq.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    //Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}
```

any changes needed so that if I send links it will be come a hyper link.
Plus I would appriciate if any one help me with send image as well just like whatsapp click of clip logo to include image file.
thanks

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392820/how-to-send-images-and-website-link-through-gcm) is a bit old but might be helpful?

Comment: I am looking for  the answer Idon't care if it is old or new I need help.